# Not able to load a layout after a list view

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I wrote xml like this but how to call this in main acivity like that need to show the card view after the list view.In my main activity welcome post is not visible. I need to show that layout at the end of my list view which is fetching from my data base

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shuan.Project.fragment.ConnectionFragment">


     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/post"
        android:id="@+id/udyopro_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/udyopost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f0f0f0"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/small_margin">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cmpny_logo"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/job_post"
            android:elevation="@dimen/standard_margin"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmpny_logo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Welcome to Udyomitra..!"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prof"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cmpny_logo"
            android:padding="@dimen/standard_margin"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="             Greetings of the day!! Welcome to a whole new world of opportunities. With the New Year ahead of us, Udyomitra will help you write a new story by setting higher goals in your life. We exposed you to all the vacancies in and around your native location by default. You will be following all your college mates and their working firms by default. We generate a decent quality resume for you for free. We will help you find the work you enjoy since you are best suited for it.We wish you all success!"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is my xml file

Error after replacing code suggested by "@patel pinkal"

```
   01-25 12:06:56.701 19657-19657/com.shuan.Project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.shuan.Project, PID: 19657
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1895)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:401)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:409)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:612)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2730)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2412)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1414)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1638)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6598)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: set List view height as wrap_content. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: no, remains same  :-(

Comment: Are you making list view visible in your code also are you attaching adapter to it?

Comment: You need to create a container around the ListView that does not extend to the full size of the Activity

Comment: Make RelativeLayout as a parent layout and include ListView inside SwipeToRefreshLayout only.

Comment: @Rohit i am making the visibility of my list view is attached with an adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollView

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    // layout content
</ScrollView>
```

for further details refer this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ScrollView)

Hope this helps.

Comment: ScrollView should **never** be used with a ListView. This is on the Android docs.

Comment: @criket_007 could you please find an answer for me?

Comment: yeah not with listView but you can put a scroll view below the listView layout and try, but you might need to change the height of the listView.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"   
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

With

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_above="@+id/udyopro_post"      
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

also replace this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/post"
    android:id="@+id/udyopro_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
```

with this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/udyopro_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
```

Comment: my app got unfortunately stopped after replacing above lines

Comment: Rendering Problems  onMeasure error (Details)  (2 similar errors not shown)  Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Comment: clean your project and then run your project, If your getting error after then post full error